# why when I resolve a promise, the output is in pending state?

Tags: javascript, promise

so consider the code below, when I resolve a `promise` the result is in `pending` state in the very first moment( I know after I expand the dropdown I will see the expected result but in here I'm questioning the very first moment), while I reject a promise, it shows the expected result in very first moment. so I wonder why is this happening?

code:

```
 const test = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 resolve(Promise.resolve(78))
 })

 console.log(test);

 //output in console:Promise {<pending>}
```

```
 const test2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 reject(Promise.resolve(78))
 })
 
 console.log(test2);

 //output:promise {<rejected>: Promise}
```

Comment: try this `const test = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 resolve(78)
 })`

`test.then((result)=>console.log(result)).catch((err)=>console.log(err))`

Comment: tnx but really looking for what's goin on under the hood in this specific scenario.

Comment: The promise body executes asynchronously

Comment: so why for `reject(1)` we can see the result instantly?@RyanPierceWilliams

Comment: @lome1446 the promise is resolved but not yet fulfilled. The promise will be fulfilled when it follows the `Promise.resolve(78)` on the next tick. Change it to `resolve(78)` instead of `resolve(Promise.resolve(78))` and you'll see that it logs `Promise {<fulfilled>: 78}` like you're expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#return_value

> Note that if you call resolveFunc or rejectFunc and pass another Promise object as an argument, it can be said to be "resolved", but still not "settled". See the [Promise description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#description) for more explanation.

The returned promise is settled async so we should create a microtask **async** to aim to the point when the returned promise is settled:

```js
const test = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(Promise.resolve(78))
})

queueMicrotask(() => queueMicrotask(() => console.log(test)));
```

[image]

Comment: can you refer to the document you have taken the first few line from it?@alexanderNenashev

Comment: @lome1446 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#return_value

Comment: tnx, I got my answer in that documentation. @AlexanderNenashev

Answer (score 0):

The `Promise` is literally a promise: a promise to provide some value later, once some work is done. So to get a value you should either await it, or provide a callback by using `then` / `catch` methods.

Basically, when you have that `test` const:

```js
const test = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(Promise.resolve(78)); // or reject(Promise.resolve(78));
})
```

You have two valid options to write deterministic code:

```
// Use callbacks:
test
    .then(result => console.log("It's for sure successfully completed."))
    .catch(e => console.log("It's for sure failed at this moment."));

// Use await:
try {
    const result = await test;
    console.log("It's for sure successfully completed.")
} catch (e) {
    console.log("It's for sure failed at this moment.")
}
```

What you're observing is just result of some internal implementation, you should not rely on that observation. This actual result could change in other JavaScript engines or in different versions.

Comment: I guessed that's because of some internal processes but I doubted it, so tnx budd@alexanderBurov

Comment: Personally I always prefere to use async await, it's easier to understand.

Comment: Can you expand on what observation you are talking about? Suggesting that `test` may not be pending within the synchronous code that created is contraindicated by console log output shown in Edge and Firefox at least.

Answer (score 0):

**Promise resolution**

The technical explanation is that pairs of `resolve`/`reject` functions are "one shots" in that once you call one of them, further calls to either function of the pair are ignored without error.

If you resolve a promise with a promise or thenable object, Promise code internally creates a new, second pair of resolve/reject functions for the promise being resolved and adds a `then` clause to the resolving promise to resolve or reject the promise being resolved, according to the settled state of the resolving promise.

Namely, in

```js
const test = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 resolve(Promise.resolve(78))
})
```

`resolve(Promise.resolve(78))` conceptually becomes

```js
Promise.resolve(78).then(resolve2,reject2)
```

where `resolve2`/`reject2` are a new pair of resolve/reject functions created for the promise `test`.

If and when executed, one of the `then` clause's handlers (namely `resolve2` in this case) will be called by a Promise Reaction Job placed in the microtask queue. Jobs in the microtask queue are executed asynchonously to calling code, where `test` will remain pending at least until after the synchronous code returns.

Note in summary: you can only *settle* a promise with a non-promise value.

**Promise Rejection**

Promise rejection is certain if a promise's `reject` function is called. Hence you can reject a promise with any JavaScript value, including a Promise object in any state.

Namely in

```js
const test2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 reject(Promise.resolve(78))
 })
```

the rejection can be performed synchronously, and the the rejection reason of `test2` is the *promise object* `Promise.resolve(78)`, not the number 78. Demo:

```js
const test2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 reject(Promise.resolve(78))
 })

test2.catch(reason => 
   console.log("reason is a promise: ", reason instanceof Promise)
);
```